# search and replace regexp gives two different outputs if grouping metacharacters are used

Tags: regex, perl, sed

I get different outputs from search and replace regexp in perl depending whether I use in place replace ([sed alternative](http://bright-green.com/blog/2003_06_08/perl_inplace_editing_howto.html)) or regular search replace and also depending on whether I use `\1` or `$1`:

```
──> cat test1.txt 
orig.avg.10

──> cat test2.txt 
orig.avg.10

# EXPECTED
──> cat test1.txt | perl -lne '$_ =~ s/(avg\.[0-9]+)/$1\.vec/; print $_'
orig.avg.10.vec

# EXPECTED
──> cat test1.txt | perl -lne '$_ =~ s/(avg\.[0-9]+)/\1\.vec/; print $_'
orig.avg.10.vec

# EXPECTED
──> perl -p -i.bak -e "s/(avg\.[0-9]+)/\1\.vec/" test2.txt
──> cat test2.txt
orig.avg.10.vec

# UNEXPECTED
──> perl -p -i.bak -e "s/(avg\.[0-9]+)/$1\.vec/" test1.txt
──> cat test1.txt
orig..vec
```

Why this happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `"` to wrap your perl code, but doing so means the shell can and will interpolate `$1`.
Use `'` instead and everything will work as expected.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that I've used in #UNEXPECTED case double quotes which makes expanding `$1` variable. Sometimes one need to write down the questions before realized the case.